# TensorRT - TensorFlow deserialization fails with Serialization Error in verifyHeader

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorrt, nvidia-docker

I'm running the [nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:19.12-tf2-py3](https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/containers/nvidia:tensorflow) docker image with the following runtime information:

- Tensorflow 2.0.0  (`tf.__version__`)
- Python 3.6 (`!python --version`)
- TensorRT 6.0.1 (`!dpkg -l | grep nvinfer`)
- cuda 10.2

I have built a model in TensorFlow 2.0 and converted+saved it to a dir:

```
1/
├── assets/
|   └── trt-serialized-engine.TRTEngineOp_0
├── variables/
|   ├── variables.data-00000-of-00002
|   ├── variables.data-00001-of-00002
|   └── variables.index
└── saved_model.pb
```

Now when I try deserializing the cuda engine with the TensorRT python API:

```py
import tensorrt as trt
TRT_LOGGER = trt.Logger(trt.Logger.VERBOSE)

serialized_engine = './tmp/unet-FP32/1/assets/trt-serialized-engine.TRTEngineOp_0'
# serialized_engine = './tmp/unet-FP32/1/saved_model.pb'

trt_runtime = trt.Runtime(TRT_LOGGER)

with open(serialized_engine, 'rb') as f:
    engine = trt_runtime.deserialize_cuda_engine(f.read())
```

I receive the following error messages:

```
[TensorRT] ERROR: ../rtSafe/coreReadArchive.cpp (31) - Serialization Error in verifyHeader: 0 (Magic tag does not match)
[TensorRT] ERROR: INVALID_STATE: std::exception
[TensorRT] ERROR: INVALID_CONFIG: Deserialize the cuda engine failed.
```

I do the saving and loading on the exact same machine, inside the exact same docker container. Am I wrong to assume that 'trt-serialized-engine.TRTEngineOp_0' contains the actual serialized model?

I have also tried doing it with the uff-parserm, but the uff shipped in the NVidia container is incompatible with tensorflow 2.0.

Any ideas how to deserialize my trt engine?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Can you please tell how did you solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @CognitiveRobot if you really want to port a TF2.X model into a C++ TensorRT environment, the most straightforward method that I found is to convert your TF model to onnx and afterwards parse the onnx to build a TRT engine.

Comment: Converting to ONNX is  ok only if you are not quantizing the model... ONNX models are no yet quantizable in TensorRT...

Answer (score 4):

If the engine was created and ran on different versions, this may happen. TensorRT engines are not compatible across different TensorRT versions. [Go to this reference for more info.](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1063354/-tensorrt-error-rtsafe-corereadarchive-cpp-31-serialization-error-in-verifyheader-0-magic-tag-does-not-match-/)

Comment: I have called build, save and read from the exact same docker container.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, if you get this error building and running on the same machine or even the same container, your tensorrt python package might have a different version than your system package try the following commands to check
In python:

```
import tensorrt as trt
trt.__version__
```

In terminal:

```
dpkg -l | grep TensorRT
```